# Add a Filter for an Attribute in Admin

Tags: magento2, admin, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I'm trying to create a filter for one of my product attributes that will consist of several dropdown menus. An example of the attribute is given below:

[image]

I want to have dropdowns for year, make, and model to reduce the number of results in the multiselect list (only 3 in the example, but will be thousands in production).

I'm new to Magento so I'm not sure where the file is to add the code, I presume in the app/code/directory somewhere. If it makes a difference, I'm using the TemplateMonster Magetique theme.

I'm not too worried about figuring out the logic behind the filtering as I have built a search similar to this before.